# Find the exact value of $\frac{BD}{AB}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Found this problem on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Ahmet____CETiN/status/1556031185121382403/photo/1).

Special thanks to [@Ahmet____CETiN](https://twitter.com/Ahmet____CETiN) to sharing this problem

All of the given data is marked in the image

[image]

My Approach.

[image]

I reflected $\triangle ADC$ over $\overline{BC}$ hoping to create an equilateral triangle and also I created $\triangle ABE$ which is congruent to $\triangle ADC$. Finally I extended  $BE$ and $D'C$ to created another equilateral triangle but that didn't helped me either.

Could anyone please help me to get a solution to this question.

Answers involving less trigonometry are much more appreciated :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Find all the angles, then use the law of sines.

Comment: @creepykrep, Accurate drawing shos the ratio is $\frac{BD}{AB}=\frac {10}7$.

Comment: @sirous GeoGebra gives the ratio as $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, very close results$10/7\approx 1.42\approx \sqrt 2$

Answer (score 1):

From triangle $ADC$ we get $AD = 2\cdot AC\cdot \sin(24)$. Now use the law of cosine in triangle $ABD$ to achieve (after some manipulations)
$$BD^2 =2 AC^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint for geometric solution:

Draw a circle center on A passing B and C. Draw another circle center on B radius equal to BD. The two circles intersect at point E. Draw the third circle it's diameter is BE and center at O.

We have tp show that AF is bisector of angle CAE, so triangles AFC and AFE are equal and we have:

$\angle AEF=\angle FCA=36^o$

$\Rightarrow \overset{\large \frown}{AGF}=72^o\Rightarrow\overset{\large \frown}{FE}=90-72=18^o $

$\Rightarrow  \angle EBF=\angle EAF=9^o$

Triangle ABC is isosceles so:

$\angle ABC=\angle ACB=36^o$

$\angle ABE=36+9=45^o $

Finally in right angled triangle ABE we can write:

$\frac {BE}{AB}=\sqrt 2$

$BE=BD\Rightarrow \frac{BD}{AB}=\sqrt 2$

Comment: "Triangle $A'BC$ is isosceles". Why?

Comment: "$AF$ is bisector of $\angle CAE$". Why?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, I edited my answer.

Comment: @rogeryen, I edited my answer, that is what we have to show.

Comment: I see. I have one more question. Do we know that $A$ is on circle $O$?